# How to create a white-on-black style for LaTeX listings

Tags: latex, listings, typesetting

I've been looking at Philip Bunge's post on [how to create a "Tango" style with LaTeX listings](http://pbunge.crimson.ch/2008/12/tango-syntax-highlighting/), and trying to adapt this to make the default text style white and the background black (this is for slides, not an article!). This is what I added:

```
\definecolor{Black}{gray}{0.0}
\definecolor{White}{gray}{0.9}
...
\lstset{
  basicstyle=\color{White},
  backgroundcolor=\color{Black},
  ...
}
```

This assumes that `basicstyle` sets the default style of all text. The listings documentation says this:

> basicstyle is selected at the beginning of each listing. You could use \footnotesize,
>   \small, \itshape, \ttfamily, or something like that. The last token of  must not read any following characters.

The output of this still shows "default" text as black. It is possible to set *more* style directives that cover most tokens in a given programming language, but even doing this some tokens (such as brackets and other punctuation) will be missed. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Here's the original line from the documentation: `\lstset{backgroundcolor=\color{yellow}}`. So maybe you just typed to many `{`s and `}`s (just a vague guess.

Comment: That's a good thought; I made the change, but sadly it didn't make any difference :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following code worked for me, but I converted the `.dvi` file to a `.pdf` in order to have the text appear as white, so it might have been your viewer?  I'm using `xdvi` and `xpdf`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{theWhite}{gray}{0.9}
\definecolor{theBlack}{gray}{0.0}
\lstset { basicstyle=\color{theWhite}, backgroundcolor=\color{theBlack} }
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
((lambda (x) `((lambda (x) ,x) ',x)) '`((lambda (x) ,x) ',x))
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for this, and is sort of helps! You're using article, I was using Beamer; you were writing lambda-calculus, I was writing Python; so you're answering a slightly different question than the one I asked. Otherwise, there are only two differences between your code and mine, one is that you used gray rather than rgb to define white / black (this doesn't seem to make any difference) and secondly you are not using the rest of the "tango" style from the blog post I linked. It seems to be the stuff in tango that's causing the problem, rather than Beamer, XDVI, Python or anything else.

Comment: OK, a bit more digging and I've found the issue, there was already a \basicstyle directive in Philip Bunge's stuff and I stupidly missed it. D'OH. Thanks for your help.

Comment: No problem!  I haven't used Latex since college so it was fun to dive back into it, even briefly!

Comment: With work pdflatex. I'd like to have a version that doesn't use \lstset and will try to figure it out.